# Variable not defined when create Link/relationship between nodes with JSON

Tags: json, neo4j

I'm experiencing an issue when I try to link / create a relationship between two nodes created just before. I have a node `A` and `B`, like this:

Node A:

`WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap('{"element1": "an element1", "element2": "an element2"}') as items CREATE (ve40:Asset) SET ve40 = items`

Node A is created:

```
DEBUG:neobolt:[#1C42]  C: RUN 'WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(\'{"element1": "an element1", "element2": "an element2"}\') as items CREATE (ve40:Asset) SET ve40 = items RETURN ve40' {} {}
DEBUG:neobolt:[#1C42]  C: PULL_ALL
DEBUG:neobolt:[#1C42]  S: SUCCESS {'t_first': 11, 'fields': ['ve40']}
DEBUG:neobolt:[#1C42]  S: RECORD * 1
DEBUG:neobolt:[#1C42]  S: SUCCESS {'bookmark': 'neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx36', 'stats': {'labels-added': 1, 'nodes-created': 1, 'properties-set': 3}, 'type': 'rw', 't_last': 0}
```

Node B:

`WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap('{"element1": "an element1", "element2": "an element2"}') as items CREATE (ve17:Asset) SET ve17 = items`

Which is also created like node A.

But when I try to add a Link between them:

`WITH apoc.load.json("{'another': 'element'}") as link, (ve40)-[ed90:LINKED]->(ve17) SET ed90 = link RETURN ed90`

I have the following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `ve40` not defined

But `ve40` has already been created just before: What did I do wrong here ? Thank you !

Comment: Run all the statements at once. If u run them one after the other, there is no way the cypher engine can keep track of variables like ve40.

Comment: Variables (like `ve40`) aren't persisted to the db, they only exist at most for the duration of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run all the statements at once. If u run them one after the other, there is no way the cypher engine can keep track of variables like ve40.